# Yii2 Creating url to folder inside root

Tags: php, yii2

My problem is somewhat simple but despite trying different Yii2 functions I'm unable to get the correct URL to the audio player components I would like to install.

So, to keep things short. Yii2 is installed on localhost with localhost/yii2app/ being the index. This is based on yii2 advanced app and the structure is as follows:

```
-Yii2app
-- frontend
-- backend
-- ...
-- flashplayer
```

Now, When i'm in sample view I would like to display the player to play the deisred sample. The url path of location is:

`http://localhost/yii2app/frontend/web/sample/1`

I wish to implement the player in this view:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" value="<?= Url::to('/flashplayer/', true); ?>player.swf" width="200" height="20" id="dewplayer" name="dewplayer">
    <param name="movie" value="<?= Url::home(false) . '/flashplayer/' ?>player.swf">
    <param name="flashvars" value="mp3=test.mp3" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

As you can see I've trying different approaches, but no success so far. I'm getting following urls:

`/yii2app/frontend/web/flashplayer/player.swf`

or

`http://localhost/flashplayer/player.swf`

Obviously, both of them are incorrect. The URL **I need** is:

`/yii2app/flashplayer/player.swf`

Is it possible to get just the main path of application without controller's route in url? I don't want to include the webroot path, but server one. Also, this should work even when the application is moved to production server.

I will appreciate any ideas.

Comment: why you don't use relative path eg. `../../../flashplayer/player.swf` ?

Comment: Seems weird to me that the `yii2app`-folder would be the configured web server index while this should normally be the `frontend/web` directory.

Comment: @Blizz well, you are right, I'm using the frontend module and I could place the player sourcecode in there. Wouldn't be hard to link it then. But I wanted to have it in a place where it can be accessed by different modules as I want to avoid code duplicating. Kind of how common folder works...

Comment: The idea is that your DocumentRoot points INTO one the web folder of the top folders, usually frontend, not that you make all your source available via the webserver. That's a hack waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can copy your index.php,assest,css,favicon.ico and robots.txt from yii2app/frontend/web/  and then pasted them in yii2app file and replace your index.php in the yii2app file with:

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/frontend/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/main-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/frontend/config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/frontend/config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

and then when you open yii2app in the localhost you can see your frontend/web
with this url:

```
localhost/yii2app
```